# Production web api hosting, web app for containers or azure container instances?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-container-instances

I have an ASP.NET core 3.1 based web api ready to deploy to Azure for production use. For test / development, I have been deploying it to a traditional app service on Azure which I believe is a shared Windows VM under the hood. I have been on F1 tier and it suits my needs for test and dev.

But for production, even the cheapest plan costs me $93.44 per month which I would like to avoid if I can.

[image: production plan suggested by Azure]

In order to **lower the cost**, I have decided to containerize my app and deploy it using "web app for containers" or "azure container instances". My question is, based on your experience, which method will give me reasonable production-scale performance while minimize my monthly cost? Or would containerize my app save me any money at all?

Please note that I have evaluated Azure Functions and decided it is not what I would like to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirements, first of all, you need to know that the Azure Container Instance benefits for its quick start and running. See this:

> Azure Container Instances is a great solution for any scenario that
>   can operate in isolated containers, including simple applications,
>   task automation, and build jobs.

It's good for the simple application, but not good for scenarios where you need full container orchestration, including service discovery across multiple containers, automatic scaling, and coordinated application upgrades. And I think it's also not stable for the production use, it's more appropriate for the test.

And the Azure App Service is cost according to the service plan, the service plan billed on a per second basis. You can plan the use with time as you need and the App Service has more features than Container Instance. Or if you do not satisfied with App Service, maybe you can take a look at the [Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/index), it has more control and feature then the Container Instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Charles Xu, "the service plan billed on a per second basis"... can you provide the link of the reference?

Comment: @sean717 You can see the [App Service Billing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/).

Comment: @sean717 Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: I'm wondering, the Azure Container instances are also billed per second they are running. But if you are hosting a webapp in a container instance and get for example 1 request per day, does it charge you for running the entire day then? Or does it quickly start up the moment it receives a request and then stops again?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Of course, it will cost when the container instance is in the running state.

Answer (score 0):

As of beginning of 2022 looks like Container Instances and Web Apps for containers will be the same ~32eur which is a bit better than the app service ~50eur.